# ratings_for getting error in ajaxful_rating_jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

in my post index view i am calling this and this error occur

undefined method `singular_class_name' for ActionController::RecordIdentifier:Module

Extracted source (around line #20):

17:       <%= post.name %>

18:       <%= post.description %>

19:       <%#=debugger%>

20:       <%= ratings_for post, :static, :small => true, :dimension => :speed %>

21:       <%#= ratings_for post, :static, :small => true, :dimension => :beauty %>

22:       <%#= ratings_for post, :static, :small => true, :dimension => :price %>

23:       <%= link_to 'Show', post if can? :show ,post %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by place following in gem: gem 'ajaxful_rating', '3.0.0.beta6'

```
 then bundle:update

  my routes:

 Contest::Application.routes.draw do |map|

 map.resources :users, :member => {:rate => :post} do 
   |nested| nested.resources :posts    
 end
```

Try please....

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by place following in gem:
`gem 'ajaxful_rating', '3.0.0.beta6'`

then bundle:update

my routes:

`Contest::Application.routes.draw do |map|`

map.resources :users, :member => {:rate => :post} do |nested|
    nested.resources :posts
  end

But seems like :stars option is not properly working(5 stars always even I want to display 10 stars)

Try it.